# Spring Integration: exception on receiving message

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

Within our Spring Integration application, when a message is received, an exception is thrown and the transformer does not receive the message.
I think it could be due to the content of the message, as messages of type String are processed correctly.

The following is the signature of the transformer for this message type:

```
@Transformer
public String transform(Message inboundMessage){
```

Have also tried

```
@Transformer
public String transform(Byte[] inboundMessage){
```

but in both instances, the following exception is thrown:

```
2013-10-14 07:21:33,547 D|DefaultMessageListenerContainer         |Received message of type [class com.solacesystems.jms.message.SolTextMessage] from consumer [Cached JMS MessageConsumer: com.solacesystems.jms.SolQueueReceiver@13b5500] of session [Cached JMS Session: com.solacesystems.jms.SolSession@1fa0f19]
2013-10-14 07:21:33,579 W|DefaultMessageListenerContainer         |Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
java.lang.RuntimeException: UTF-8 format error
    at com.solacesystems.common.util.UTF8Util.getStringFromUTF8(UTF8Util.java:272) ~[sol-common-6.0.0.146.jar:na]
    at com.solacesystems.jms.message.SolTextMessage.load(SolTextMessage.java:82) ~[sol-jms-6.0.0.146.jar:na]
    at com.solacesystems.jms.message.SolTextMessage.getText(SolTextMessage.java:69) ~[sol-jms-6.0.0.146.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.extractStringFromMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:177) ~[spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.fromMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:94) ~[spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:266) ~[spring-integration-jms-2.2.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:537) ~[spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:497) ~[spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468) ~[spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:326) [spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:264) [spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1071) [spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1063) [spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:960) [spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_06]
2013-10-14 07:21:33,579 D|SolMessageConsumer                      |Entering receive(), timeout: 1000
2013-10-14 07:21:34,391 D|SolMessageConsumer                      |Leaving receive()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's not getting as far as the transformer. The problem is within the Solace library when Spring is calling `getText`...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: UTF-8 format error
at com.solacesystems.common.util.UTF8Util.getStringFromUTF8(UTF8Util.java:272) ~[sol-common-6.0.0.146.jar:na]
at com.solacesystems.jms.message.SolTextMessage.load(SolTextMessage.java:82) ~[sol-jms-6.0.0.146.jar:na]
at com.solacesystems.jms.message.SolTextMessage.getText(SolTextMessage.java:69) ~[sol-jms-6.0.0.146.jar:na]
at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.extractStringFromMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:177) ~[spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
...
```

It looks like the library thinks the data is in UTF-8 format when it's not.

Comment: Gary, thanks. Is it possible  that Spring is calling getText() and therefore Solace is treating the message as text even though it is not? Is there a way to tell Spring Integration that this is not a text message but a binary one?

Comment: No; the message converter will only call `getText()` if it's a `TextMessage`; it clearly *is* a text message (`SolTextMessage`); it's the character encoding that is somehow wrong. It looks like whatever is producing the message is causing the problem. Binary data should be stored in a `BytesMessage` not a `TextMessage`. The type of the message that Spring tries to convert is controlled by the broker, not Spring.